# How to disable the link dashboard for subscribers?

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

Is there outside the entrance to block a dashboard for non-admin users a way only to block the Dashboard link and allow changing their profile as password? In example for only subscriber.

```
function blockuser_init_redirect(){
  if( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') && ( current_user_can('subscriber') || current_user_can('contributor') ) ){
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('init','blockuser_init_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_admin_users' );
/**
 * Redirect non-admin users to home page
 *
 * This function is attached to the 'admin_init' action hook.
 */
function redirect_non_admin_users() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will also block that the user can’t change their profile information such as password..